# Is my pip with virtualenv working? creating a new virtualenvironment and it says django already satisfied?

Tags: python, pip

I installed pip, virutalenv and set my WORKON_HOME etc. according to the insturctions.

Now I did this:

```
mkvirtualenv test1
```

then did:

```
pip install django
```

and got:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
```

In terminal, it does have (test1) at my prompt....

Does this just mean, no need to download and install since we found and copied it locally?

**Actually doing lssitepackages doesn't show django...what's wrong here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
mkvirtualenv --no-site-packages test1
```

Then, your env will be actually clean and isolated.

Comment: i swear I was doing that...but it works now thanks man! thanks a 'bundle'!

Answer (score 1):

On OS X, that folder in /Library is in the default search path, so if Django got installed in there, it will satisfy the dependency for pip. Maybe you wanted to use the --no-site-packages option when creating the virtual env?

Comment: yeah, well I just thought the whole point of virtualenv was to isolate things from site-packages....and not even look there!

Comment: i'm using the virtualenvironment wrapper also, --no-site-packages doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Virtualenv CAN make an isolated site-packages, but by default, will also make whatever is in the system site-packages available too.